# Issue with Resource manager connection while submitting map reduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform, resourcemanager

I am getting resource manager connecting issue while submitting map reduce job in Hortonworks Hadoop cluster.

15/12/03 16:58:27 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /:8050
15/12/03 16:58:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/03 16:58:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/03 16:58:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/03 16:58:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/03 16:58:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/03 16:58:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /:8050. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=50, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score 0):

After restarting zookeeper from Ambari this issue resolved.